# American (Private) Ankylosing Spondalytis Health insurance costs compared to the British NHS

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, health-insurance

I'm a sufferer of Ankylosing Spondalytis, and a resident of the UK - my health care is handled by the National Health Service (NHS).  Now in the UK seems to be increasing move to privatise it's health service, and there are scare stories about the UK adopting US like private healthcare scheme.

My question is do/did U.S. patients (customers) diagnosed with Ankylosing Spondalytis pay a premium, and is their health care more expensive compared to the UK - irrespective of the severity of the disease.  Does Obama Care resolve any insurance inadequacies?

Answer (score 2):

At this time, if a US resident with a pre-existing condition tries to buys health insurance privately, the insurance company will likely want to do one or more of the following:

1. *Exclude* the pre-existing conditions from coverage for the duration of the policy.
2. *Cover the pre-existing condition after a waiting period* of N months where N  can be anywhere from 3 to 12 or more.
3. Offer a policy with so large a premium that it will be out of reach of the customer.
4. Decline to offer a policy at all.

Things are somewhat different if the customer will be getting coverage under a group health care policy from his/her employer. As I understand it, the  Affordable Care Act will eliminate #1 and #4 above (possibly #2 as well),
but I do not believe that the Act regulates the premiums that can be charged by the policies offered in the marketplaces.

Comment: ObamaCare deals with all 4 of the issues, and currently #1 and #4 are illegal already, #2 and #3 will be outlawed in 2014 when the law comes to its full effect.

Comment: Actually since the OP has continuous coverage through the NHS he could get in with out any waiting period.  That said the OP would probably be put into the high risk group which would fall into number 3.  And @littleadv - It will not be outlawed the states will have to set up high risk pools to provide the coverage...  not a single state has done this yet.

Comment: @Chad, high-risk pools are interim solution, once the law kicks in, coverage cannot be denied, and prices will be regulated. As to continuous coverage through the NHS, the OP asks what happens in the US from the perspective of the UK system becoming the same, not because he wants to move to the US. Unfortunately my original comment disappeared, but what I said was that it is more likely for the US to move towards the UK system than the other way around, as nowhere in the world other than the US elected officials would stay in office after allowing the poor and sick to die.

Comment: And even in the US, only the small minority of the tea party folks openly suggest to let people who are poor to die, everyone else agrees that the health system in the US is insane. I wouldn't worry if I were in the OP's place.

Comment: @littleadv - I work in insurance. I understand how it works. Coverage can not be denied but a private insurer can essentially deny you by giving you a rate the 99% can not afford. The high risk pools are supposed to compete with the insurers keeping the rates reasonable. But the way it will most likely play out is that insurers simply will not compete for business they do not want. It is the reason the credit card guys target professionals and students instead of the housing projects. They only want business they can make a profit on.

Comment: @Chad: "They only want business they can make a profit on" - that's the main problem. As long as its true, the healthcare in this country will be in a horrible situation. I can't possibly understand why someone would be allowed to make profit on someone else's life or death, but that's just me. In any way, there's no chance it will happen in Europe. I hope at some point we'll have health system where the decision whether a person lives or dies is not based on how much money he has, as they have.

Comment: @Chad again, you understand how it works, but its not how its going to work in the future. "*The program doesn’t charge you a higher premium just because of your medical condition, and eligibility is not based on income.*": http://www.healthcare.gov/law/features/choices/pre-existing-condition-insurance-plan/index.html  And of course, starting of 2014, pre-existing conditions cannot be used to deny coverage or charge higher rates from individuals.

Comment: @litteadv - That is true so long as you are already in a policy.  But if you do not have insurance then you get rated just like you would today.  You will end up either paying a huge rate or in the high risk pool.  The pools with be treated like medicaid today so people in the pools will get the worst appointment times(coincodence surely) not get to pick their doctors, and their treatment will not be the same.  It will be like being in the UK now except that those with money or power will get priority.  And once you are in the pool good luck getting out.

Comment: @Chad but since coverage cannot be denyied, "if you do not have insurance" doesn't exist. Worst case, a person gets a high-risk pool insurance with more limited coverage for half a year, and then moves on to any other insurer (because now he does have insurance). So the argument doesn't stand, and that's the whole point of the law - not to let this argument stand.